# Change background of WPF DataGrid cell depending on value when populated with a datatable as IListSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatrigger

I have seen similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381726/wpf-datagrid-row-background-based-on-cell-value)

However, they don't seem to answer my question. I have a XAML datagrid in a WPF application

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="1" AlternationCount="2" HeadersVisibility="Column" Name="dgSkillsMatrix" Margin="0,0,0,1" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White" VerticalGridLinesBrush="White" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFD0D0EB" RowBackground="#FFECECF5" FontSize="12">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Temp">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, I have tried a number of different ways to "Trigger" the colour change, but none of them fire. If I put a generic setting in abouve the triggers it will change the colour.

I think the problem is that I am binding to the datagrid from a dynamic set of data that could change day to day, so I am using a datatable (below), as there is a varying number of coulmns that mean I can't use objects for each row, as I never know when the number of columns/properties would change.

```
this.dgSkillsMatrix.ItemsSource = (dt as IListSource).GetList();
```

I just need to know how to fire a trigger to change properties depending on that value of a cell created from a datatable to listsource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this [link](http://codefornothing.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/the-wpf-datagrid-and-me/) offer any assistance?  It appears that binding to a DataTable may cause a few issues for cell colouring, have you tried implementing a data converter and MultiDataBinding as the article suggests?

Comment: Yes, that's great Alex. But I am still getting an error:

 Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='#FFFFFFFF' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')

Comment: Try to wrap the value in a SolidColorBrush: new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));

Comment: Yeah mate, that was the issue. This works:

return new SolidColorBrush((System.Windows.Media.Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFF66"));