# How do I hide a Datagrid Row at a certain index?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid and would like to hide certain rows in the DataGrid based on what row index they are. An example of what i mean is that if I have a DataGrid with rows:

```
Mike  //Index 0
Steve //Index 1
Smith //Index 2
Greg  //Index 3
Jake  //Index 4
```

and I want to hide all names that start with S, is there a way to do something like

```
dataGrid1.row[1].Hide; 
dataGrid1.row[2].Hide;
```

or something like

```
dataGrid1.row[1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
dataGrid1.row[2].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I do not want to change anything really within my XAML I want to strictly be able to hide a row within my WPF code.

I've seen some really long multiple method ways but is there a way to do this, similarly to

```
dataGrid1.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

where you can easily hide a column?

Thanks, iato

**Edit:** What I was looking for was an addition to the potential duplicate question.

```
            var row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
            row.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

was my final solution :)

Comment: `DataGridRow` has a `Visibility` property. In your XAML, use the DataGrid's RowStyle property to set a style on the rows. In the style, write a trigger -- in the XAML -- which, in the XAML, sets the row's Visibility to Collapsed based on some property of the row object. You may want to write a [value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) or [multi value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If you have a valid reason to avoid XAML, please share. It's rare, but not entirely unheard-of.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Okay thank you I will try this. I typically like to do my Screen Design in XAML, while having my Screen Population, Interaction, Logic and Business Rules in WPF.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am also fairly new to XAML but have used c# for some time so I am more comfortable with WPF to XAML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get DataGrid row by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413259/get-datagrid-row-by-index)

Comment: @ASh I just want to be able to hide the rows, I already know what Index my rows are on.

Comment: @iato If you how how the datagrid is populated, I can write an example showing how to do this.

Comment: @iato, read again. the post shows how to get DataGridRow object by known index. Then you can do `row.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`

Comment: @ASh would you look at that! That worked perfectly and was what I was wanting!! Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

Data bind the grid to a collection in the ViewModel. In the Data Template use a binding for the visibility of outermost element and a converter to convert the name field in the collection to visibility.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Visibility={Binding Name, Converter={{StaticResource NameToVisibilityConverter}} >
    ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the Converter - for example:

```
Convert() { return name[0] == 'S' ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible; }
```